# How do I highlight the Html.ValidationMessage's on a AJAX Post?

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc

I have a form which I post back via jQuery AJAX. In my controller it checks for errors in the ModelState and returns these errors in a ContentResult and the user sees the errors in an updated DIV.

How can I get the little * next to the fields when there are errors?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have returned the modelstate as a JSON object. The on the OnSuccess event I loop through the errors and find a span with the modelstate key name and set it to visible.

Answer (score 0):

It's just a class name.  `input-validation-error`.  You can use jquery to parse the result for error properties and add the class to the appropriate elements.

Comment: At what point are the inputs created though? At the point of the AJAX post I don't think the inputs will have been created.